# Las variables nunca llegan a PHP desde la API FETCH

Tags: php, fetch

Tengo 3 archivos (**HTML**,**JS** y **PHP**) en el de **HTML** meto la información en una variable llamada **DatosPaciente** con JavaScript

```
function Tomar_DATOS(){            
  DatosPaciente={
    id:document.getElementById("paciente_id").value,
    fecha:document.getElementById("fecha").value
};}
```

Después uso una función llamada **Tiene_Cita_Hoy** dentro de un archivo **JS**

```
Tiene_Cita_Hoy(DatosPaciente)
```

En el archivo **JS** utilizo la **Fetch API** para mandarle los valores al archivo de **PHP**

```
function Tiene_Cita_Hoy(Datos){
console.log(Datos);//"{id: "8", fecha: "2020/09/03"}" Esto es lo que me regresa TODO BIEN
    fetch('tiene_cita.php',{
        method: 'POST',
        body: Datos
    })                           
        .then(res => res.json()) 
        .then(data => {                     
            console.log(data); //to see the result
        })
 }
```

Después en el archivo **PHP** trato de recibir la información vía **POST**

```
  $VALOR_id_paciente=$_POST['id']; 
  $VALOR_fecha=$_POST['fecha'];
```

y se la signo a una query

```
$SQL="SELECT * FROM vhsagenda WHERE PACIENTE='".$VALOR_id_paciente."' AND FECHA='".$VALOR_fecha."'";
echo json_encode($SQL);//Solo para confirmar que información tiene
```

pero el resultado siempre es: `SELECT * FROM vhsagenda WHERE PACIENTE='' AND FECHA=''`

al parecer la información nunca llega al archivo  PHP

Comment: primero asegurate de que los estas enviando datos a la funcion Tiene_Cita_Hoy(DatosPaciente) podrias estar enviandole nada.

Answer (score 2):

Muchas gracias a todos pero ya encontré la solución, en el archivo **HTML**, para asignar los valores se forma como si se pasaran datos por url

```
DatosPaciente = 'id=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("paciente_id").value) + '&fecha=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("fecha").value);
```

y regresa lo siguiente: `id=8&fecha=2020%2F09%2F04`

Después en el archivo **JS**, se tiene que agregar un encabezado en el **FETCH** antes del **body** donde recibe la información para ser enviada

```
headers:new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}),
```

al parecer, se necesita para que **FETCH** lo pueda procesar para el archivo **PHP** y finalmente el **POST** puede recibir la información y ahora si la **query** de **SQL** queda así:

```
SELECT * FROM vhsagenda WHERE PACIENTE='8' AND FECHA='2020/09/04'
```

Comment: Excelente! agrega una pequeña explicación para la definición del header y la preparación **manual** de la cadena de datos. (Que es casi equivalente a procesar el form, pero más general pues permite tomar información de cualquier elemento o atributo en la página) Ah! y **no olvides aceptar la respuesta**

Answer (score 0):

Me puedo estar equivocando pero creo que como estas enviando la información en el *body*, no vas a obtener los valores como si vinieran de un formulario. Tienes que cargar el *payload* del request.

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json);
```

Y en `$data` tendrías el json que enviaste.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-receive-json-post-with-php/